# how can I default selected value in asp:DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I default selected value in asp:DropDownList?

Following is my code:

```
<tr>
    <th align="right"><strong>Test: </strong></th>
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="Test" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTest"
        DataValueField="TestID" DataTextField="TestName" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>  
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test %>"
        SelectCommand="test_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
   </td>
</tr>
```

How can I able to selected the display list which is the TestID is 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have couple of options first one is below if you want to do this by default.

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
```

Or you can do this in code

```
Test.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add it after data bind from the code behind?

```
<tr>
    <th align="right"><strong>Test: </strong></th>
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="Test" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTest"
        DataValueField="TestID" DataTextField="TestName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" ondatabound="AddDefaultItem">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>  
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test %>"
        SelectCommand="test_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Then in code behind:

```
protected void AddDefaultItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
}
```

UPDATE:

After reading the last sentence it sounds like you might want the list item that has value 1.  do do this use the code below:

```
Test.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
```

Hope one of these works for you.